# ePub menus don't work in iBooks

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents, ebook, ibooks-author

I created an ePub from InDesign. When I open it in Adobe Digital Editions the menus work as they should. When I open it with Apple iBooks on an iPad, clicking  menu loads the book cover. Every menu selection seems to do this.

I've tried searching online for solutions but have come up empty.

Any suggestions? Help!